# Is Yu Hai's Praying Mantis Internal?

Tags: tai-chi, wushu, internal

We often think of Mantis as external, deriving from Shaolin, and regularly teach it to kids and teens, b/c it's both fun and has some useful techniques, and trains in both strength, speed and flexibility.  But [Yu Hai](http://www.kungfumagazine.com/magazine/article.php?article=688)'s *Tong Long* ([Northern Mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Praying_Mantis)) looks more internal than external:

[Yu Hai in the film *Shaolin Temple* (1982)](https://youtu.be/gqagZNrKSgs?t=1101)

[Wushu Classics Master Yu Hai Tang Lang Quan (Praying Mantis) 1977 于海武术螳螂拳](https://youtu.be/yWSVNblqH-o?t=4)

- Is Is Yu Hai's Praying Mantis internal?